# Как организовать синхронизацию локальной копии кода между разными машинами (между коммитами)?

Tags: php, git, ide, netbeans, синхронизация

**Имеем:**

- разработческий и продакшен-версии проекта (сайта), LNAMP;
- один разработчик, разработческий комп, NetBeans 8, синхронизируемый проект (локальная копия, синхронизация при сохранении);
- гит-репозиторий, под гитом - только удаленные копии (дев и продакшен), но не локальная копия (по большому счету, используется лишь для деплоя изменений и контроля боевой среды на предмет внедрения вредоноса);

до этого момента все было хорошо и удобно, НО!

- возник второй комп (теперь в офисе), с которого иногда тоже хочется покодить;

**Задача:**

- организовать синхронизацию кода между этими разработческими компами (причем, синхронизацию МЕЖДУ коммитами... поделал дома, поделал на работе, вернулся домой, доделал, закоммитил, начал новый таск, уснул, на работе продолжил... и желательно с минимальным оверхедом на переключение между "дома" и "на работе");

**Какие варианты НЕ подошли:**

- гит, встроенный в нетбинс; потому что моя задача - синхронизация именно МЕЖДУ коммитами; меня тут на Тостере активно склоняют к тому, что надо юзать гит и коммитить/пушить при каждой пересадке между машинами... но идея упирается в неизбежные 100500 wip-коммитов вместо одного логически завершенного рабочего изменения - меня сильно смущает... (аменд - невозможен, т.к. предыдущий коммит уже запушен... единственный выход - периодически наводить порядок ребейс-сквошем, но это много лишнего гемора)...
- полный даунлоад проекта перед тем, как начинать работать; самый феншуйный, но самый долгий вариант (ради получаса работы ждать час, пока он все скачает, а потом еще полчаса, пока взбесившийся SASS все перекомпилирует - занятие бестолковое);
- штатный синхронизатор НетБинса; во-первых, тоже медленный, т.к. один хрен чуть ли не весь код сначала выкачивает для сверки, а во-вторых - частенько ошибается в направлении синхронизации, и доверять ему слепо - нельзя, надо еще выверять глазами... в итоге, в пол-часа можно уложиться, но всеравно ради получаса работы - такое себе;
- оставить проект удаленно, без локальной копии; сразу все становится грустно и медленно, особенно, когда работаешь вне дома по мобильному инету... аплоад-он-сейв - и та порой подбешивает, но это периодически и терпимо, а если все там держать - то бекграунд-скан, поиски, саджесты и т.п. - вообще повергают в уныние; уж не говоря о счете за мобильный интернет )

**Какие варианты пока только в голове:**

- оставить проект синхронизируемым (он сейв). но держать локальную копию на гуглдрайве/ядиске/дропбоксе... плюсы: по ощущениям, в синхронизацию они умеют сильно лучше, чем нетбинс, к тому же - сделают это в фоне, и к моменту когда я созрел поработать - локальная копия будет уже свежей... минусы: от SASS-рекомпайла не спасет; безопасность - ибо все конфиги, пароли и явки окажутся в облаке, а там и до выдачи Яндекса недалеко)))

**Вопрос:**

- собственно, есть ли у кого-то опыт решения подобной задачи? Может я какого-то очевидного варианта не вижу?

Заранее благодарен за любые идеи )

Comment: Чтобы понять что вам надо, достаточно объективно смотреть на вещи. `синхронизация именно МЕЖДУ коммитами` - вы можете называть это как угодно, но по факту это и есть другая версия проекта, создайте третью ветку, и пуште туда, то что 100500 коммитов, ничего страшного, он для этого и создан, закончили работать в одном месте - пуш, потом в другом покодили - пуш и так далее. ничего страшного что 100500. если ветка девелоперовская там не должны быть боевые патчи.

Comment: Идеология тут такая (в системах контроля версий), что какая-то новая фишка выделяется в отдельную ветку. Там делается 100500 коммитов. И только когда функционал будет готов и оттестирован - сливается с мастером. Чтобы не сталкиваться с ребейсом, нужно стараться работы делить на не пересекающиеся множества. Это тяжело и местами нереально.

Comment: меня смущает скорее то, что потом этои 100500 коммитов при слиянии тянутся в мастер, и навигация по истории становится почти невозможной.. ну т.е. когда я на одной машине, то привык коммитить только законченные изменения (пусть их несколько внутри таска)... сделал А - коммит, сделал Б - коммит, протестил, пофиксил баги - коммит, мердж...   или я чего-то не знаю, и мерж может НЕ тащить промежуточные коммиты в мастер, а оставить только один?

Comment: ... поигрался с rebase-i и merge--squash - оба порождают потом кучу лишних слияний и конфликтов... первый - при последующей "пересадке" с домашнего компа на рабочий (100500 коммитов на втором компе-то никто не схлопнул, в итоге - их приходится сливать со схлопнутым коммитом, в результате имеем 100501 коммит вместо 100500), а во втором случае - при следующем merge-squash, т.к. мастер остался не-синхронизированным (по сути) с дев-веткой...  короче, я уже че-т запутал сам себя :))) подскажите уже, как НЕ тащить эти 100500 микро-коммитов в мастер?

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас разрешен ребейс-сквош, то и аменд разрешен. Разницы между этими командами нет.

"Запрещено" делать изменения в коммитах которые являются предками для чужих коммитов, например в master и других публичных ветках. А если это ваша личная ветка с коротким временем жизни, то смело делайте много коммитов и амендов к ним.